# Hangouts alternative video call URL

Tags: video, url, chat, google-hangouts

When I start a video call in hangouts, I'm directed to an URL like this:

https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/?authuser=(etc,etc,etc)

The problem is that, in my company, the `plus.google.com` domains are considered as social network domains, thus blocked for access.
I can use `gmail` normally and the text connection of `Hangouts`. But every time I try to start a video call, I'm redirected to `plus.google.com` then I cannot open it.

Is there another URL for `hangouts` video call, with a domain different than `plus.google.com`, such as `google.com/hangouts/etc` or `gmail.com/etc`?